# ARM Assembly: Values stored by scanf are not saved correctly.

Tags: assembly, arm, scanf, libc

I am trying to read several values (one at a time) with scanf in ARM Assembly. I manage to get the scanf portion working and it apparently saves the values right. But when i want to retrieve them I only get the last number right and the other ones get something else.

This is what it is giving me:

```
Enter a number: 1  
Enter a number: 2  
You entered: 2129322344 and 2.
```

It should say `You entered 1 and 2.`

My code looks like this:

```
  .global main
  .func main

main:
  PUSH {LR}
  LDR R0, =entryMessage
  BL printf
  SUB SP, SP, #8
  LDR R0, =scanformat
  MOV R1, SP
  BL scanf        @ Number is saved in SP - 8
  LDR R0, =entryMessage
  BL printf
  ADD SP, SP, #4
  LDR R0, =scanformat
  MOV R1, SP
  BL scanf        @ Number is saved in SP - 4
  ADD SP, SP, #4  @ Restore SP to original
  SUB SP, SP, #8  @ Prepare to read SP - 8 for first number
  LDR R1, [SP]    @ Read first number
  ADD SP, SP, #4  @ Prepare to read SP - 4 for second number
  LDR R2, [SP]    @ Read second number
  ADD SP, SP, #4  @ Restore SP to original
  LDR R0, =printMessage
  BL printf
  POP {PC}

_exit:
  BX LR

.data
  entryMessage: .asciz "Enter a number: "
  scanformat: .asciz "%d"
  printMessage: .asciz "You entered: %d and %d.\n"
```

Can someone tell me why is it that only the last value gets read correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `ADD SP, SP, #4` before calling `scanf` for the second time, then the call overwrites the previous value entered. You could store them in reverse order, before loading into `R1` and `R2`. So the stack pointer is never higher than a stored value you want to use.

```
main:
    PUSH {LR}
    LDR R0, =entryMessage
    BL printf

    SUB SP, SP, #4  @ Reserve space for the first number entry
    LDR R0, =scanformat
    MOV R1, SP
    BL scanf        @ Number is saved at original SP - 4

    LDR R0, =entryMessage
    BL printf

    SUB SP, SP, #4  @ Reserve space for the second number entry
    LDR R0, =scanformat
    MOV R1, SP
    BL scanf        @ Number is saved at original SP - 8

    LDR R2, [SP]    @ Read second number
    ADD SP, SP, #4  @ Prepare to read first number
    LDR R1, [SP]    @ Read first number
    ADD SP, SP, #4  @ Restore SP to original
    LDR R0, =printMessage
    BL printf

    POP {PC}
```